# Footer line - change it length

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm trying to achieve a footer line, which would only be a fraction of length of the whole footer, like this:

[image]

Is there any way to do it? I am using article.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you mean by "footer line": Are you talking about the line that separates footnotes from the body of the page, or are you talking about a general-purpose line that separates the footer row(s) from the body of the page? And, when you write "only be a fraction of length of the whole footer", which fraction do you have in mind? Should the length of the footer line be allowed to vary from page to page? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico Hi, I meant the lane that's above the footer and separates the footer from the body of the page. Sorry for not making it clearer in my post, I'm a newbie. I can make the lane using footrulewidth, just not sure how to make it shorter and alligned to the left.

Comment: Do you use the `fancyhdr` package at present?

Comment: @Mico Yes. that's what I'm using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using the `fancyhdr` package, you could issue the instruction

```
\renewcommand\footrule{\hrule width0.5\textwidth}
```

to typeset a footer rule whose width is `0.5\textwidth`. (By default, `\footrule` is defined as `\hrule`.) If you want the thickness of the footer rule to be, say, 1pt, you'd write

```
\renewcommand\footrule{\hrule width0.5\textwidth height1pt}
```

A small MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt} % optional
\rhead{\thepage} % display page number top-right
\renewcommand\footrule{\hrule width0.5\textwidth}
\cfoot{} % don't display page number in middle of footer line
\lfoot{Stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff}

\begin{document}
Hello World.
\end{document}
```