# How to have a footer without any data in Latex?

Tags: header-footer

I want to have a footer in my latex document but without any data in it. I only want to have a line as my footer. Is it possible to have something like that ?

Comment: Welcome, you could try the `fancyhdr` package (`\usepackage{fancyhdr}`) and use `\pagestyle{fancy}` followed by `\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}` or whatever dimension you prefer. In the future, could you provide more information such as what document class, footer or header packages you are using please, it is easier to help. Hope this helps!

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276358/text-on-background-image-footer-and-header

Comment: Thanks @LaccaseTVersicolor, it worked. Is there also a way to increase the length of the footer ? My text body is smaller than the header and footer.

Comment: I'm not sure what "length" means in regard to a footer; do you mean "height"? or "width"?, or "distance from the bottom of the page to the top (or bottom) of the footer"?, or "distance from the top of the page to the top of the footer", or something else? For any of these, though look into the [geometry](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry?lang=en) package.

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem. How have you got the text narrower than the headers and footers? Why do you want to increase the length of the footers when the text body is already narrow?

Comment: @lqope54 you could try the following [answer by Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/535655/245306) if you mean length as in how far across the page the footer goes. Other then that, it would be good to create a small tex example to edit into your question with screenshots of how your page looks right now so people can help.

Comment: @LaccaseTVersicolor I have posted an answer bassed on your comment but I have a feeling that you might be able to provide a better one. Please do so and I will do my best to delete mine,

Comment: @PeterWilson I am happy with your answer, glad my comments were of use! I will delete this comment tomorrow so this question is not cluttered but it's no issue at all

Answer (score 1):

This is partly based on @LaccaseTVversicolor's comment.

An altered definition of `\footnoterule` is;

```
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{vspace*{-3pt}%
  \hrule width 2in height 0.4pt \vspace*{2.5pt}}
```

Change this to suit you typographic preference.